# How to pass google service account to the dataproc_operator for creating datproc cluster using cloud composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-iam

I'm trying to pass a specific service account to cloud composer DataprocClusterCreateOperator task dag. I am not able to set the service account while adding the service account name (as a string)to the service_account field in the dag and service account has datprocAdministrator role.
Getting error "Not authorized to requested resource."

[dag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrIvJ.png)

Still it showing show below error :

returned "Not authorized to requested resource."

--------------LOG--------------

[2019-10-25 09:05:14,965] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:14,964] {models.py:558} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/temp_rahul_f.py
[2019-10-25 09:05:15,802] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:15,801] {cli.py:520} INFO - Running  on host airflow-worker-554db5655d-dsdvp
[2019-10-25 09:05:15,920] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:15,918] {dataproc_operator.py:404} INFO - Creating cluster: composer-pyspark-cluster-demo-20191024
[2019-10-25 09:05:15,968] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:15,968] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:94} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2019-10-25 09:05:16,002] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:16,002] {discovery.py:272} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dataproc/v1beta2/rest
[2019-10-25 09:05:16,156] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:16,156] {discovery.py:873} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/the-text-255813/regions/us-central1/clusters?alt=json
[2019-10-25 09:05:16,441] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 49: Subtask create_dataproc_cluster [2019-10-25 09:05:16,440] {http.py:121} WARNING - Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "forbidden"
[2019-10-25 09:05:16,442] {models.py:1846} ERROR - https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/the-text-255813/regions/us-central1/clusters?alt=json returned "Not authorized to requested resource.">
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1714, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py", line 411, in execut
    if self._get_cluster(service)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py", line 230, in _get_cluste
    cluster_list = self._get_cluster_list_for_project(service
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py", line 225, in _get_cluster_list_for_projec
    region=self.regio
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrappe
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execut
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri

---

Comment: Issue is resolved with setting adequate permission to the service account.

Comment: Running into the same issue, what was the adequate permission?